# Java convert a list to a map of sets with grouping by key

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

Say I have a list of objects called `Student`. Object `Student` is defined as

```java
public class Student {
    private String studentName;
    private String courseTaking;
}
```

In the list of students, there can be multiple student objects with the same `studentName` but different `courseTaking`. Now, I want to turn the list of students into a map of `studentName` and `courseTaking` like so

```java
Map<String, Set<String>>
```

The key is `studentName`, and the value is all of the `courseTaking` of the same student put together as a `Set`. How can I do this using `stream()` & `collect()`?

Comment: When you ask how to do it "using lambda expressions", do you actually mean to ask how to do it using Streams? Because it can be done with Streams and method references *(assuming getter methods exist)*, without any lambda expressions, so the question to you would be why it has to use lambda expressions?

Comment: Yeah I did mean to use stream(). Sorry for not being clear in the first draft. I can turn the list into a map of list using groupBy(), but I can't figure out how to turn that into a map of set.

Comment: So you have repeated `Student` objects for each course the student is taking ? Definitely doesn't feel right. The courses should be an array in the `Student` object directly.

Comment: `students.stream().collect(groupingBy(Student::getStudentName, mapping(Student::getCourseTaking, toSet())))`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;


public class StackOverflow {

  private static class SO46310655 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      final List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();
      students.add(new Student("Zoff", "Java 101"));
      students.add(new Student("Zoff", "CompSci 104"));
      students.add(new Student("Zoff", "Lit 110"));
      students.add(new Student("Andreas", "Kotlin 205"));
      Map<String, Set<String>> map = students.stream().collect(
          Collectors.groupingBy(
              Student::getStudentName,
              Collectors.mapping(
                  Student::getCourseTaking,
                  Collectors.toSet()
              )
          )
      );
      System.out.println(map);
    }

    public static class Student {
      private final String studentName;
      private final String courseTaking;

      public Student(String studentName, String courseTaking) {
        this.studentName = studentName;
        this.courseTaking = courseTaking;
      }

      public String getStudentName() {
        return studentName;
      }

      public String getCourseTaking() {
        return courseTaking;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

yeilds `{Andreas=[Kotlin 205], Zoff=[Java 101, CompSci 104, Lit 110]}`